# Problems re-indexing Category Products and Products Categories in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, category, reindex, index

*We are facing the Reindex for the Category Products and Product Categories and we are getting the following error while reindexing through SSH* ***(php bin/magento indexer:reindex)***

***Category Products indexer process unknown error:***

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4-5' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT  INTO `temp_catalog_category_tree_index_6be8e2c1` (`parent_id`,`child_id`) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?)
```

***Product Categories indexer process unknown error:***

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4-5' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT  INTO `temp_catalog_category_tree_index_83868f3d` (`parent_id`,`child_id`) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?)

[root@server public_html]# php bin/magento indexer:status
+-----------------------------+------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
| Title                       | Status           | Update On | Schedule Status | Schedule Updated |
+-----------------------------+------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
| Catalog Product Rule        | Ready            | Save      |                 |                  |
| Catalog Rule Product        | Ready            | Save      |                 |                  |
| Catalog Search              | Ready            | Save      |                 |                  |
| Category Products           | Reindex required | Save      |                 |                  |
| Customer Grid               | Ready            | Save      |                 |                  |
| Design Config Grid          | Ready            | Save      |                 |                  |
| Google Product Feed         | Ready            | Save      |                 |                  |
| Google Product Removal Feed | Ready            | Save      |                 |                  |
| Inventory                   | Ready            | Save      |                 |                  |
| Product Categories          | Reindex required | Save      |                 |                  |
| Product EAV                 | Ready            | Save      |                 |                  |
| Product Price               | Ready            | Save      |                 |                  |
| Stock                       | Ready            | Save      |                 |                  |
+-----------------------------+------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
```

Please kindly help us.